# Correct way to expand custom WordPress plugin functions

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I have written a plugin (procedural way) and I am trying to understand wich is the best approach to expand some of its functions by creating an other small plugin (which should expand the main plugin) for a specific site which requires some additional functionality.

I have inspected other plugins to get an idea, but they mainly make use of classes and objected oriented PHP is something I am not expert on.

I thought about these different approaches but I am not sure which is the correct one.

**EDIT:**

If they are all correct (as I seem to understand from other users' comments) and if:

1. there's no one which is partucularly better over another
2. and their implementation just depends on the developer's implementation strategy

feel free to let me know and I will mark the answer as correct.

**Option 1**

```
// In additional plugin:

/**
 * Remove original function (from main plugin)
 */
add_action('plugins_loaded','remove_hooks');
function remove_hooks(){
    
    if(function_exists('name_of_function')){
        remove_action('name_of_action', 'name_of_function');
    }
}

/**
 * Call customized function
 */
add_action( 'name_of_action', 'name_of_customized_function' );
function name_of_customized_function() {
    // Rewriting the whole (customized) function
}
```

**Option 2**

```
// In main plugin:
add_action( 'init', 'name_of_function' );
function name_of_function() {
    
    do_action('custom_hook_one');
    
    // Some code...
    
    do_action('custom_hook_two');
    
    // Some more code...
}


// In additional plugin:
add_action( 'custom_hook_one', 'expanding_the_function' );
function expanding_the_function() {
    // Adding some code to expand main function
}

// In additional plugin:
add_action( 'custom_hook_two', 'expanding_the_function_even_more' );
function expanding_the_function_even_more() {
    // Adding some code to expand main function
}
```

**Option 3**

```
// In main plugin:
add_action( 'init', 'name_of_function' );
function name_of_function() {
    
    if(function_exists('expanding_function_from_additional_plugin_part_one')){
        expanding_function_from_additional_plugin_part_one();
    }
    
    // Some code...
    
    if(function_exists('expanding_function_from_additional_plugin_part_two')){
        expanding_function_from_additional_plugin_part_two();
    }
    
    // Some more code...
}



// In additional plugin:
function expanding_function_from_additional_plugin_part_one() {
    
    // Adding some code to expand main function
}

function expanding_function_from_additional_plugin_part_two() {
    
    // Adding some code to expand main function
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but as there is no "definitive best way", the answers you'll get are primarily opinion based. And as such, this question doesn't fit well for StackExchange in my opinion. To give my two cents: Option 2 feels most natural WP to me.

Comment: You need to be able to mark an answer as not just the best way, but the correct way, written and answered using facts, as the canonical correct answer for all users with this question. You will need to adjust your question so that this is possible. Remember this isn't a discussion forum thread, it's a question answer site

Comment: Many thanks for your considerations. I've just edited the question so that you can provide a more 'boolean' answer.